# _free_base "Error reading register value"

Tags: c++, encryption, runtime-error, crypto++

I have some code from my test application:

```
char* buff = new char[0];
f_hStream.read(buff, size);
string cut_header = zCrypto::from_base64( string(buff, size) );

if ( cut_header.length() == 0 ) break;

const char* dec = zCrypto::decrypt( cut_header );
printf( "Header >> %s\n", dec );
vector<string> header = split(string(dec), ';');
```

#### `decrypt` function >

```
const char* zCrypto::decrypt(const std::string& str_in) {
    const string key = zCrypto::from_base64("<base_64line_here>");
    const string iv = zCrypto::from_base64("<base_64line_here>");

    std::string str_out;
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::Rijndael>::Decryption decryption((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());

    CryptoPP::StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
        new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(str_out)
        )
    );

    return str_out.data();
}
```

And i getting debugger error on line **const char* dec = zCrypto::decrypt( cut_header );**, if i trying to launch application without *MVS* debugger, he just crash - `Application has stopped working...`

P.S. I can't change `Code Generation` - `Runtime Library` from **/MT**, cryptopp functions in my app compiling without errors only with this type.

Decryption works fine too, whats I do wrong?

### UPDATE:

I change

```
const char* zCrypto::decrypt(const std::string& str_in) {
```

to

```
string zCrypto::decrypt(const std::string& str_in) {
```

and

```
char* buff = new char[0];
const char* dec = zCrypto::decrypt( cut_header );
```

to

```
char* buff = new char[size];
string dec = zCrypto::decrypt( cut_header );
```

**I'm still getting error.**

Comment: This is legal (but questionable): `char* buff = new char[0]`. However, the subsequent use is undefined. Often you just put a buffer on the stack: `char buff[500]; size_t size = sizeof(buff);`. It also keeps you out of the memory manager. This is also undefined: `str_out.data()` because the string is allocated on the stack. The pointer is no longer valid once the function returns.

Comment: Related: if you think C-style-casting a `c_str()` to something non-const is a good idea, it isn't, in particular since the IV is likely to be updated. Stuff those things in `std::vector<byte>`

Comment: *"I can't change Code Generation..."* - You need to change this function to: `string dec = zCrypto::decrypt( cut_header );`. Then, `decrypt` will return `str_out`, and not `str_out.data()`.

Comment: @jww - I updated the question, I try this before :c

Comment: Check out this thread...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999481/free-c-throws-exception-with-this-program-has-stopped-working
maybe you try to read from a place in the memory which is already deleted

Answer (score 1):

This line does not sound right.

```
char* buff = new char[0];
```

You probably need:

```
char* buff = new char[size];
```